# Underflow and Overflow in binary addition

Tags: binary, overflow, undertow

In the case of:

```
0b10001111+0b10011000 = 0b100100111
```

Is a case of underflow? as the two term are negative and the result it positive?

When will we get an overflow? as the 9th bit will be always 1? when both of the 8th bits are 1

Comment: `Is a case of underflow?` Yes. `When will we get an overflow? as the 9th bit will be always 1?` There is no 9th bit in a 8-bit integer.

Comment: @tkausl 9th bit allegedly

Comment: @tkausl this says that it is overflow http://sandbox.mc.edu/~bennet/cs110/tc/orules.html

Comment: Seems like they don't use the term `underflow` at all.

Comment: @tkausl that is way I am confused, there some that say that if the carry bit is the same so it is not under/overflow

Comment: What do you mean by _if the carry bit is the same_?

Comment: @tkausl https://www.eecis.udel.edu/~davis/cpeg222/AssemblyTutorial/Chapter-08/ass08_23.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 0b1000 1111+0b1001 1000 = 0b1 0010 0111

Including the carry as n+1th bit of result in *meaningless* for 2s complement. What you can do is either to stick on the original size

> 0b1000 1111+0b1001 1000 = 0b0010 0111 // invalid

or extend operands to n+1 bits and get a n+1 bits result.

> 0b1 1000 1111+0b1 1001 1000 = 0b1 0010 0111 //valid

The reason is that 2s complement works by adding 2^n to negative integers to make them positive. (to code a<0=-|a|, use 2^n+a or 2^n -|a|, ie the complement to 2^n of |a|, hence the name of 2s complement).

This is great, as the coded value is (2^n)+a if a<0 or a if a≥0, and if you ignore 2^n, you can do signed integer addition without worrying on the sign of operands. But you *must* ignore the carry out (except for what concerns validity).

To get the precise validity rules, you must consider the different situations:

1/A,B>=0

[image]

Result is valid iff MSB=0 ⇒ c_n-1=0 (and we always have c_n=0)

2/ A,B<0

[image]

Result is valid iff MSB=1  ⇒ c_n-1=1 (and we always have c_n=1)

3/ A>=0, B<0

[image]

Result cannot be too positive or too negative and is always valid. And we always have c_n=c_n-1

We can see that the global rule that indicates if a result is valid is that c_n==c_n-1 (or c_n ⊕ c_n-1 indicates overflow).

There are many other equivalent rules. For instance:
result is valid if (sign(A) != sign(B)) or ((sign (A) == sign(B)) and (sign(A)==sign(A+B))
which can be expressed in C as
`((a^b) | (a^~(a+b)))&(1<< sizeof (int) -1)`